# How to dynamically define CQLEngine models?

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlengine, datastax-python-driver

I am using Datastax's Cassandra Python driver's Object Mapper for defining cassandra table columns. I am trying to define the models at run time (that's the requirement). The table and column names and column types are resolved at run time.

I am trying to define a cassandra cqlengine model at runtime using `type` to define a class.

Looks like the `Model` class defined on the Python driver has added a metaclass to `Model`:

```
@six.add_metaclass(ModelMetaClass)
class Model(BaseModel):
...
```

Is there even a way to define Models using type?

I am seeing the following error while defining a Model class:

```
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns as Columns

attributes_dict = {
    'test_id': Columns.Text(primary_key=True)
    'test_col1': Columns.Text()
}

RunTimeModel = type ('NewModelName', tuple(Model), attributes_dict)
```

Error:

```
RunTimeModel = type ('NewModelName', tuple(Model), attributes_dict)
TypeError: 'ModelMetaClass' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a simple syntax error trying to construct a tuple from a non-sequence argument.

Instead, you can use the tuple literal notation:

```
RunTimeModel = type ('NewModelName', (Model,), attributes_dict)
```